# External Harddrive: Compatible Partitions types

Tags: linux, windows, macos, hard-drive, filesystems

I have an external harddrive, which has a partition of NTFS and 300 GB of unallocated space. Is it possible to use that unallocated space to create a paartition on Macos? The disk utility doesn't let me add a new partition. Is it because Macos can't work with drives that contain a NTFS partition?

On the same hardrive, with LinuxMint 20.3, I can't create exfat partition but I can create FAT32 on unallocated space along with existing NTFS. As, exfat got added into the newer kernel which I don't have in my latest LinuxMint, is it possible to create an exfat partition along with ntfs, these days on new linux kernel based OS such as Ubuntu 22.04?

Secondly, Is it possible to create exfat along with NTFS on a same drive?  Or, Is it possible to create APFS and exfat on the same drive?

Comment: Windows does not support formatting a disk with APFS nor does it have native support for it.

Comment: To enlarge on @Ramhound's comment, there are third-party tools that can access APFS partitions: https://www.intowindows.com/3-ways-to-open-apfs-drives-in-windows-10/ . That said, I've found *writing* to non-native file systems risky. As for exFAT, though I don't suggest purposely using that file system, the *fuse* package can enable Linux to read and write to it: https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-mount.exfat-fuse/

Comment: @Ramhound So if a disk has APFS has one of its partition, with some unallocated space or some other Partition, Windows can't access any of it? (without using third party tools that act as a bridge between these Filesystem and native Filesystem)

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I was using Gparted, and my drive has an existing NTFS Partition. I wanted to create exfat Partition on remaining unallocated space. But gparted did not let me choose exfat, when I way trying to use that unallocated space into a new partitions

Comment: You haven't actually told us what the structure of the drive is, so we're guessing. Bear in mind, Mac cannot write to NTFS natively, it will not offer to make new partitions if the drive is on MBR with NTFS. Neither Windows nor nix can read APFS. [Paragon NTFS for Mac](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/) will enable read/write for NTFS on Mac.

Comment: @Tetsujin By structure do you mean one of the GPT or MBR or also some thing else? Do you know if its possible to check on Macos? I am certain that one partition is NTFS

Comment: Run `diskutil list` in terminal & add the relevant section to your question [select & hit Ctrl/K to format it for SE]